# Conditional statement if a substring occurs 1 time in a line read from a file

Tags: regex

Example file:

```
RDH205xxx 123 456 ABC
RDH205xxx 123 456 RDH205yyy
RDH205yyy 654 32A
RDxxxxxxx 456 789 BC205yyyy
```

tried:

```perl
open and read a line from a file
if (/RDH{1,1}$/) { parse the line }
```

Comment: Please add expected output/result

Comment: The expected output will be the line with only 1 occurrence of RDH.

Comment: The expected output will be the line with only 1 occurrence of string RDH. I will then use these lines to parse/split the individual pieces of data within the line I need.  the file is only an example of data in a large file with many lines not containing string RDH within the line. the lines with string RDH included either contain 1 occurrence or 2 occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -ne 'print if scalar s/\bRDH\b/RDH/g == 1' file
```

Comment: I was trying to use:           
elsif (/RDH{1,1}$/) { 
                               : # if matching only one occurrence of "RDH" found in a file line
                               }

Comment: That's the purpose of my command